# Activate WPGlobus in ACF TextArea

Tags: translation, advanced-custom-fields, multilingual

I have the WPGlobus Plus plugin installed. While I can see the WYSIWYG language tab in Advanced Custom Fields, I can't for the life of me figure out how to activate / change the languages for the non WYSIWYG textarea. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited in their own support area. I've not heard of that plugin before. You'd likely find more help here with more commonly used/supported plugins like WPML.

Comment: Interesting @aibrean is WPML more widely supported? I saw that wpglobus had much more people rate it and highly than WPML, so I thought it had a bigger user base.

Comment: Builtwith data says 467K sites use WPML right now. While the WPGlobus plugin has 14k active websites. When I look at third-party plugins and what they support, I commonly see WPML. I've never seen WPGlobus.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. YOAST ACF plugin was causing the problem. I deactivated it and everything now works fine.